# ¿Cómo crear distintas instancias de un mismo sitio en un mismo servidor?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Actualmente tengo un sitio web (LAMP) que permite realizar evaluaciones mediante cuestionarios asociados a una institución y usuarios. De esta forma si otra organización desea utilizar esta herramienta para su evaluación hay que replicar el sitio en otro servidor y volver a parametrizarlo.

Entonces lo que busco es poder hacer una especie de paso previo al login de usuarios y hacer un login para administradores y por cada administrador obtener una instancia limpia del sitio. ¿Es eso posible mediante PHP? ¿Cómo replicar instancias de un sitio ya armado?

Comment: No es posible, tienes que hacer manejo de bases de datos donde a cada usuario se le asigna una empresa en específico, y de esta forma cada empresa tiene su propia información a su disposición

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no me parece que sea algo factible , lo que deberias hacer es separar toda la informacion con un empresa_id en tu base de datos, y asi mostrar a cada empresa solo su información.
para el usuario final es transparente ya que solo verá su informacion.

Comment: tambien puedes crear manualmente otra instancia en el mismo servidor asignandole otro puerto en apache, aunque no lo veo nada práctico.